# ParalleTable can't use 100% CPU

Tags: parallelization

I have two notebook. A.nb and B.nb. When I run the ParalleTable in A.nb, it will use 100% CPU. But I change some items in A.nb to get B.nb. When I run B.nb, it only used 50% CPU.

I can't find the issue. I hope someone can help me because now B.nb will cost really much time to calculate it.

Parallelization calculation in "rules". 
There is only one difference between A.nb and B.nb is the definition of eqnst[t].
Following are codes, if you want to download the notebook, please click [the link of ONEDRIVE](https://stuouceducn-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/qiantian_stu_ouc_edu_cn/Efn4m8Ee_0ZGppCgRaXagH8B6dFigY4WckbM9cq3Pf3CQA?e=yB5ipo).

*A.nb*

```
Clear[n, \[Lambda]s, xs, tvalues]
n = 501;
\[Lambda]s = 
  Symbol["\[Lambda]" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[n](*number of sites*);
xs = Append[\[Lambda]s, \[Beta]];
tvalues = Range[0., 0.05, 0.0025] (*set of t values*);

Clear[eq, eqnst]
eq[t_] := Block[{U = 1., \[Mu] = 0.5, EE, summand},

   EE[k_] := (-2  t ( Cos[(2 \[Pi]  (k - 1))/n])) - \[Mu];

   summand[\[Lambda]_, 
     k_] := (U/(2 n)) (Cosh[\[Lambda]]^2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 + 
        2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^4 + 
        2 \[Beta]^2 Cosh[\[Lambda]] Sinh[\[Lambda]] + 
        4 \[Beta]^2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 ) + Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 EE[k];
   Total[MapIndexed[
      summand[#, #2[[1]]] &, \[Lambda]s]] + ( \[Beta]^2 (-2 t - 
        0.5)) + (U/(2 n)) (\[Beta]^4)

   ];

eqnst[t_] := eqnst[t] = Thread[D[eq[t], {xs}] == 0]

rules = ParallelTable[{t, 
     FindRoot[
      eqnst[t], {xs, RandomReal[{-3., 3.}, Length[xs]]}\[Transpose], 
      Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}, 
      MaxIterations -> 10000]}, {t, tvalues}, {i, 100}(*{i,
    100} it is used to generate 1000 times former part*)] // Union // 
  Chop
```

*B.nb*

```
Clear[n, \[Lambda]s, xs, tvalues]
n = 501;
\[Lambda]s = 
  Symbol["\[Lambda]" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[n](*number of sites*);
xs = Append[\[Lambda]s, \[Beta]];
tvalues = Range[0., 0.05, 0.0025] (*set of t values*);

Clear[eq, eqnst]
eq[t_] := 
  Block[{U = 1., \[Mu] = 0.5, \[Epsilon] = (-2 t - 0.5), EE, summand},

   EE[k_] := (-2  t ( Cos[(2 \[Pi]  (k - 1))/n])) - \[Mu];

   summand[\[Lambda]_, 
     k_] := (U/(2 n)) (Cosh[\[Lambda]]^2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 + 
        2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^4 + 
        2 \[Beta]^2 Cosh[\[Lambda]] Sinh[\[Lambda]] + 
        4 \[Beta]^2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 ) + Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 EE[k];
   Total[MapIndexed[
      summand[#, #2[[
         1]]] &, \[Lambda]s]] + ( \[Beta]^2 \[Epsilon]) + (U/(2 n)) (\
\[Beta]^4)

   ];

newD\[Beta][t_] = 
  Block[{U = 1., \[Mu] = 0.5, \[Epsilon] = (-2 t - 0.5), EE, summand2},
   summand2[\[Lambda]_] := (U/n) (Cosh[\[Lambda]] Sinh[\[Lambda]] + 
       2 Sinh[\[Lambda]]^2 );

   \[Epsilon] + (U/n) (\[Beta]^2) + 
    Total[MapIndexed[summand2[#] &, \[Lambda]s]]

   ];

eqnst[t_] := 
 eqnst[t] = 
  Append[Thread[D[eq[t], {\[Lambda]s}] == 0], newD\[Beta][t] == 0]

rules = ParallelTable[{t, 
     FindRoot[
      eqnst[t], {xs, RandomReal[{-3., 3.}, Length[xs]]}\[Transpose], 
      Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}, 
      MaxIterations -> 10000]}, {t, tvalues}, {i, 100}(*{i,
    100} it is used to generate 1000 times former part*)] // Union // 
  Chop
```

Because code is too long, so I upload the notebook to the Onedrive. This link is AB.nb.
https://stuouceducn-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/qiantian_stu_ouc_edu_cn/Efn4m8Ee_0ZGppCgRaXagH8B6dFigY4WckbM9cq3Pf3CQA?e=yB5ipo

Comment: This is feature of hyperthreading. Each CPU kernel supports two threads and, thus, task manager gives you 50% usage..

Comment: But it is really strange when I run A.nb, the task manager shows 100% CPU usage.